# Comments on approvals in azure pipeline

Tags: azure, pipeline

Is there a way to add comments or just text to an approval in azure pipelines?
And if so, is it possible to show variables that are used in the run?
I need to display some variables in the window below.

*Ignore the red part*

[image: approval window]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to add comments or just text to approval in azure pipelines?

Yes, you add comments or text which is optional for approving the azure pipelines.

> And if so, is it possible to show variables that are used in the run?
> I need to display some variables in the window below.

Checks can be configured on environments, service connections, repositories, variable groups, secure files, and agent pools.

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/approvals?view=azure-devops&tabs=check-pass#how-can-i-use-output-variables-from-previous-stages-in-a-check), by default, only predefined variables are available to checks. You can use a linked variable group to access other variables.